# Java Look and Feel

Tags: java, swing, look-and-feel

[image: LookAndFeel 1]
[image: Look and feel 2]

I use this code

```
setUndecorated(true);
getRootPane().setWindowDecorationStyle(JRootPane.FRAME);
```

Can someone explain me, why only one "look" paints the borders of the frame? And this is possible to fix it?

Comment: Wait, you first want to set it to *undecorated*, and then set the style for it? I can imagine that this results in undefined behavior. I'm not sure if this needs fixing from the API side...

Comment: I copied this code from [oracle tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/displayCode.html?code=https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/examples/misc/GradientTranslucentWindowDemoProject/src/misc/GradientTranslucentWindowDemo.java). The documentation states that `setUndecorated(true)` can be replaced at the same mine.

Comment: I cant see the lines you have mentioned in linked source...

Comment: Sry, i pasted the wrong code in the comment. `setUndecorated(true)` instead of `setDefaultLookAndFeelDecorated(true)`.